# Firestore Billing for Collection Group Queries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Are collection group query prices the same as a single collection query?  Or is there a minimum of one document read per collection even if the query for that collection returns no documents?   Is there anything I should watch out for when it comes to billing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minimum of one document-read per query. So if you query across a group of collections and no documents are returned, that will be charged as a single document read.

The easiest way I find to remember this is to think of the read as a change for reading the index. Since a collection group query works from a single index, it is (at least) a single document read for reading that index.

Comment: Say that query matches many documents for example 10k, but if I limited the query to the first 10, that would have cost 10 reads not 10k reads, right? TIA.

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Collections group queries are billed exactly like normal collection queries, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).  It stands to reason that if a normal query that returns no documents incurs at least one read, then collection group queries would behave the same way.